# Find max distance between an intersection and a plane.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, intersection-theory

Determine the point of intersection between the plane $x/2 + y/2 -z = -1$ and the cone
$z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ that is farthest from the plane $y = 0$

Comment: You need to show your work and add more context to your question. Before positing your question, did you read about the site? This is not a do-my-homework site. Also it may help you to read what is considered a good question on the site - https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: geogebra finds the intersection as $(1,1,2)+(-\sqrt{2}\cos{t}+\sin{t},-\sqrt{2}\cos{t}-\sin{t},-\sqrt{2}\cos{t}).$

Comment: Then maximize the absolute value of the $y$-coordinate $|1-\sqrt2\cos{t}-\sin{t}|$ to get the point farthest from $y=0$ to be $(1+\frac1{\sqrt3},1+\sqrt3,2+\frac2{\sqrt3}).$